# Pulling substring data between underscores

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a column called OriginalFileName in table [Import].  The data looks like below.  The format is ID_LastName_FirstName_etc.  I am trying to write a statement that will pull the ID, LastName, and FirstName into their own columns.

```
2900411_DOE_JOHN_1013273960_SMITH_012018-122018_TEST_1023194929605635701.pdf
```

I was able to get the ID and last name using this:

1. ID:

SELECT LEFT(OriginalFileName, charindex('_', OriginalFileName) -1) from IMPORT

2. LASTNAME (underscore value keeps disappearing when I copy and paste so I have replaced the underscore symbol with the actual word):

SELECT SubString(OriginalFileName, (CHARINDEX('underscore', OriginalFileName, 0) + 1),(CharIndex('underscore', RIGHT(OriginalFileName, (LEN(OriginalFileName) - (CharIndex('underscore', OriginalFileName, 0)))), 0) - 1)) from IMPORT

3. FIRSTNAME:

?????????????????????????????

However, I am having a lot of trouble getting the first name out.  Please assist.  The length of the data separated by underscores will vary.  I got those two other statements from other posts but was unable to figure out how to modify in order to get the first name value.

Comment: Some versions of SQL have some functions that can make this easier, such as string_split. What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one method, **assuming** that surname and forename are the 2nd and 3rd parts respectively, and there are more parts afterwards:

```
SELECT V.Filename,
       SUBSTRING(V.Filename, SN.CI+1, FNs.CI - SN.CI -1 ) AS Surname,
       SUBSTRING(V.Filename, FNs.CI+1, FNe.CI - FNs.CI -1 ) AS Forename
FROM (VALUES('2900411_DOE_JOHN_1013273960_SMITH_012018-122018_TEST_1023194929605635701.pdf')) V(Filename)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',V.Filename)))SN(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',V.Filename,SN.CI+1)))FNs(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',V.Filename,FNs.CI+1)))FNe(CI);
```

Comment: If I want to do this for all data in column OriginalFileName, how would this be modified?

Comment: Just use your column's name instead, @DavidSmith .

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but received an error "OriginalFileName is not a recognized table hints option."  Is this an issue with my SQL server version?  I do not have the ability to edit the compatibility level.  The error message indicated it should be set to 90.

Comment: Huh? Why are you specifying a table hint, I don't use them in my solution at all. I'm guessing you don't understand the above solution, what about it are you struggling with? Thev`CHARINDEX` or the `SUBSTRING`? What have you tried using my solution? Could you post a DB<>Fiddle?

Comment: Yes sorry quite a SQL beginner.

SELECT V.OriginalFilename,
       SUBSTRING(V.OriginalFilename, SN.CI+1, FNs.CI - SN.CI -1 ) AS Surname,
       SUBSTRING(V.OriginalFilename, FNs.CI+1, FNe.CI - FNs.CI -1 ) AS Forename
FROM MedicalRecordRetrievalImportDetail V(OriginalFilename)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',V.OriginalFilename)))SN(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',V.OriginalFilename,SN.CI+1)))FNs(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',V.OriginalFilename,FNs.CI+1)))FNe(CI)

Comment: What is `V(OriginalFilename)`? Tables don't require aliases for columns (and I doubt your table only have one column)

Comment: `(VALUES(...) V(Filename)` is the sample data in my query (as we had but a single string to work with here), you need to replace that with your table, and the column name in the rest of the query

Answer (score 1):

Just another option.

Not clear if the positions are fixed to **Pos2** and **Pos3**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,OrginalFileName varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2900411_DOE_JOHN_1013273960_SMITH_012018-122018_TEST_1023194929605635701.pdf')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(OrginalFileName,'_','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider, doing this with a series of update statements to parse column by column.  Less elegant than @Larnu's, but maybe more flexible.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000) = '2900411_DOE_JOHN_1013273960_SMITH_012018-122018_TEST_1023194929605635701.pdf'
DROP TABLE #results
CREATE TABLE #results (origstring VARCHAR(MAX), col1 INT, lnm VARCHAR(10), fnm VARCHAR(10), col4 VARCHAR(20), col5 VARCHAR(20), col6 VARCHAR(20), col7 VARCHAR(20), col8 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #results (origstring)
SELECT @str

UPDATE #results
SET col1 = LEFT(origstring, CHARINDEX('_', origstring) - 1)
, origstring = right(origstring, len(origstring) - CHARINDEX('_', origstring))

UPDATE #results
SET lnm = LEFT(origstring, CHARINDEX('_', origstring) - 1)
, origstring = right(origstring, len(origstring) - CHARINDEX('_', origstring))

UPDATE #results
SET fnm = LEFT(origstring, CHARINDEX('_', origstring) - 1)
, origstring = right(origstring, len(origstring) - CHARINDEX('_', origstring))

UPDATE #results
SET col4 = LEFT(origstring, CHARINDEX('_', origstring) - 1)
, origstring = right(origstring, len(origstring) - CHARINDEX('_', origstring))

--etc, for the rest of  the columns
```

Each step basically cuts the first part off of the remaining original string and inserts it into a column.

Comment: How can this be modified so I can get the substring out of an entire column of data called OriginalFileName?

Comment: It shouldn't need to be modified at all - the `update` statements will run on the whole table if you replace my `#results` table with the actual table of data you have.  You may need to add column into which to place your substrings if they do not already exist.

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace `select @str` with the actual column of your original substring, in which case the code would create the `#results` temp table, drop your data in, and run the updates on all of your original strings.